# How to include different number of objects at compile time with variadic arguments in the initializer list?

Tags: c++, templates, initialization, compile-time

This is an extension of previous question ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63792255/how-to-include-different-number-of-objects-at-compile-time-in-the-initializer-li))

I need to include a different number of objects depending on the provided 'define' and with different ctor parameters. First parameter is an 'index' of object from zero and to (NUMBER-1), other parameters are optional.

So far I don't have issues when only single 'index' parameter is presented but I'm still straggling to add optional parameters `Args... args`.

That's how I'm trying to do that. Let's say we are gonna to instantiate 2 following classes

```
class Output
{
public:
    explicit Output(uint32_t idx) : m_idx(idx) { printf("ctor: %u\n", m_idx); };
private:
    uint32_t m_idx = -1;
};

class Input
{
public:
    explicit Input(uint32_t idx, std::string name) : m_idx(idx), m_name(name) { printf("ctor: %u [%s]\n", m_idx, m_name.data()); };
private:
    uint32_t m_idx = -1;
    std::string m_name;
};
```

There are 2 templates to instantiate with sequential indexing

```
template<typename T, typename... Args, typename TInts, TInts... I>
constexpr auto MakeArrayHelper(Args... args, std::integer_sequence<TInts, I...>)
{
    return std::array<T, sizeof...(I)>{ (I)..., std::forward<Args>(args)... };
}

template <typename T, size_t Count, typename... Args, typename BaseType = uint32_t>
constexpr auto MakeArray(Args... args)
{
    return MakeArrayHelper<T>((args)..., std::make_integer_sequence<BaseType, Count>());
}
```

And I wanted to instantiate classes like that

```
    auto outputs = MakeArray<Output, 5>();
    auto inputs = MakeArray<Input, 3>(std::string("Analog"));

    expanded into:
std::array<Output, 5> = { Output{0}, Output{1}, Output{2}, Output{3}, Output{4} };
std::array<Input, 3> = { Input{0, "Analog"}, Input{1, "Analog"}, Input{2, "Analog"} };
```

This leaves me with a compilation error: `could not deduce template argument for 'TInts'`

Could you help me with understanding what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. No one should have to assemble a reproducible example out of fragments and fill in missing `#include` directives.

Comment: I see an attempt at a solution, but I'm not clear what problem it's trying to solve. Could you describe what the helpers are supposed to expand to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to give a full answer without a full example but... I see some problems in `MakeArrayHelper()`

First of all, the variadic pack of parameter has to be in last position, or the deduction fails.

So, instead of

```
template<typename T, typename... Args, typename TInts, TInts... I>
constexpr auto MakeArrayHelper(Args... args, std::integer_sequence<TInts, I...>)
```

you can try with

```
template<typename T, typename TInts, TInts... I, typename... Args>
constexpr auto MakeArrayHelper(std::integer_sequence<TInts, I...>, Args ... args)
```

Second: if you want use forwarding, the `args` arguments has to be forwarding references

```
template<typename T, typename TInts, TInts... I, typename... Args>
constexpr auto MakeArrayHelper(std::integer_sequence<TInts, I...>, Args && ... args)
// .....................................................................^^
```

Third: inside the function you declare a `std::array<T, sizeof...(TInts)>` but you initialize it with

```
{ (I)..., std::forward<Args>(args)... };
```

a sequence of `sizeof...(TInts)` and some `args...`.

I don't understand what you want obtain but this e clearly wrong.

--- EDIT ---

Or maybe I understand what do you want... If I understand correctly, what you want is something as (caution: code not tested)

```
template <typename T, typename TInts, TInts... I, typename ... Args>
constexpr auto MakeArrayHelper (std::integer_sequence<TInts, I...>, Args const & ... args)
{
    return std::array<T, sizeof...(I)>{ T{I, args...} ... };
}

template <typename T, std::size_t Count, typename BaseType = std::uint32_t, typename ... args>
constexpr auto MakeArray (Args const & ... args)
 {
    return MakeArrayHelper<T>(std::make_integer_sequence<BaseType, Count>(), args...);
 }
```

Avoid forwarding `args...` in `MakeArrayHelper()` because you can't (without risks) forward the same variable more than a time.

Comment: I think `T{I, args...}...` is what op wants, because the used classes each have an index member.

Comment: @IlCapitano - I think you're right: `I` isn't only to make the sequence but also an argument for the constructor. And this make also the code simpler. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: That's what I'm up to. @max66 thanks for detailed explanation.